# Definition of obstacles in new OpenAI gym environment

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I study a Reinforcement Learning algorithm that navigate an agent from one initial point to another in a complex environment where other agents and obstacles exists too.
I want to make **my own gym environment** in OpenAI to train my model. I have read that το built your own environment requires the definition of a class and functions such as init,reset,step,render etc.

Μy difficulty is in how I will design the environment that I will train my agent. I mean the plan of the room in which my agent has to navigate.How I will make the algorithm understand that my agent has found an obstacle(lets say a static obstacle). Don't this have to be done in the beginning somehow?

I would appreciate if someone could help me!!!
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: It can be almost however you want to do it. An obstacle can form part of your observation, and/or part of the reward feedback for you agent. From an observation perspective, it could be a "raw" observation based on what the agent "sees" or it could be in the form of an action mask, which is used as input into the model: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-models.html#variable-length-parametric-action-spaces